# Will I loose this content or the content will be saved?

Tags: 7, upgrading

I'm new in drupal. I have one site that is running on drupal version 7 and now needs to be upgraded. My question is: I have big content in this site, after the upgrade will I loose this content or the content will be saved?

Comment: Which upgrade you want to do i.e. core minor or major upgrade. Currently which drupal core version you have?

Comment: There is a great and comprehensive [drupal docs](https://www.drupal.org/upgrade) to upgrade the site. By reading this docs you may know about complete process of upgrading ie *Major version* or *Minor version*. I also found another useful tutorial about [Drupal Upgrade](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/drupal/drupal_upgrade.htm). Here is step by step procedure to upgrade the site.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will not loose any content after upgrading the site. But before upgrading the site please take care of the following things.

1. **Back up your database.**
2. **Back up your code.**

Answer (score 0):

Your content will be saved, but you should back up your database and all the code inside of your `sites` folder.

I used to do manual upgrades, but I found that upgrading via Drush is much easier.

`drush up` updates Drupal core and contrib projects and apply any pending database updates. `drush up --security-only` will only install security updates, which I find most useful when maintaining older sites.